# module import of same folder says not found when called from outside folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

The file layout looks like this

```
.
├── modules/
│   ├── module1.py
│   └── module2.py
└── main.py
```

**module2.py**:

```py
print('hello world')
```

**module1.py**:

```py
import module2
```

when running `module1.py` the output looks like this

```
"hello world"
```

---

**main.py**:

```py
from modules import module1
```

when running `main.py` the output looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "C:\Users\demar\Desktop\A\main.py", line 1, in <module>

        from modules import module1

    File "C:\Users\demar\Desktop\A\modules\module1.py", line 1, in <module>

        import module2

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module2'
```

Comment: you need an `__init__.py` file in the modules folder in order to tell python to treat that folder as a package

Comment: @Mouse It doesn't matter really. Python creates [Namespace package](https://peps.python.org/pep-0420/) implicitly.

Comment: Do note that imports _do not_ navigate directories. Imports are only ever resolved by searching the Python path. Every module has one and only one name that you can import it by. The fact that your code tries to use both `import module.moduleX` and `import moduleX` is a strong indication of a design problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you are in the directory of `main.py`, Python automatically adds this directory to the `sys.path`(this is where it looks for modules and packages).

So `modules` (namespace) package and `main.py` are recognizable for Python. That's why you didn't get any error running the `from modules import module1` part. Again because their directory is in the `sys.path`

Error comes from when it tries to execute `module1`, it sees `import module2` line. Now it doesn't recognize `module2`.

##### How to fix?

1. You could either add the directory of `module2.py` which is `modules/` to the `sys.path` or via `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.
2. You could change `module1.py` and import it like this:

```py
from modules import module2
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct code for **module1.py**:

```
from modules import module2
```

just because you run main.py from parent folder

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I just write

```
try:
    import module2
except Exception:
    from . import module2
```

in module1

it works from main and works from module1

Comment: Trying to expose the same module as being at two different package locations is a problematic design. It would be better to pick a single package design and stick with it: either `module` should be a top-level package, or each `moduleX` should be a top-level module. You shouldn't try to do both

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).